# If a key is stuck on my keyboard, how can I open device manager?

Tags: windows-7

If a key is stuck on my keyboard, how can I open device manager?

I am using windows 7.

Also, I have no pause-break button on my keyboard.. so if there is any shortcut involving pause-break, it won't work.

I can't do much from task manager I can't even kill a task, because the t key keeps putting it on tasks beginning with 't' and looping it through those.

I tried pulling the 't' off the keyboard and pushing away at it but no luck.

I could restart but i'd lose things I haven't saved.. I could end up saving them all with something involving the letter 't' like tttt and ttttttt   and tttttthtttttt  but really i'm hoping for a better idea.

I heard of disabling the keyboard in device manager and attaching an external one, but even if that did work, I can't get device manager open.. if I click the bottom left, the orb, then things get typed automatically into the search box and no options are available in the start menu when that happens.

I can't see control panel icon on the desktop.

If I right click the desktop and choose customize and click to show various icons then ...well some other issue...

Answer (score 2):

Not a great answer, but I happened to have a network connections window open in my taskbar.. from there I got to control panel and device manager and saw keyboard and HID keyboard and I uninstalled the HID one.. and now the keyboard actually works.

**added**
I also later found that I had an external USB keyboard plugged in and lying on the floor and something was on the usb keyboard that must have been pushing 't' on it!

Comment: Why don't you accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

A.  Unplug the keyboard so you're not getting spammed with the faulty keystroke.

B.  Click Start->Control Panel->Ease of Access->Ease of Access Center.

B2.  You can also access the Control Panel by clicking the Start Menu, and finding Control Panel on the right side.  Click Ease of Access->Ease of Access Center

C.  Click the Start On-Screen Keyboard button.

Now you can save everything, which you should be doing as a matter or course, or turn on auto-save.